# How to fix "cannot borrow as mutable" error in trie implementation?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a trie in Rust to learn the language, especially around recursive structures. In the process, I'm seeing that the `add_word` method gives me an error. The implementation is

```rust
use std::array;
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Trie {
    is_end: bool,
    pub children: [Option<Box<Trie>>; 26],
}

impl Trie {
    pub fn new() -> Box<Self> {
        Box::new(Trie {
            is_end: false,
            children: array::from_fn(|_| None),
        })
    }

    pub fn starts_with(&self, s: &str) -> bool {
        if s.is_empty() {
            return true;
        }
        let child = &self.children[(s.as_bytes()[0] - b'a') as usize];
        if child.is_none() {
            return false;
        }
        child
            .as_ref()
            .unwrap()
            .starts_with(s.get(1..).unwrap_or_default())
    }

    pub fn add_word(&mut self, s: &str) {
        if s.is_empty() {
            self.is_end = true;
        }
        let index = (s.as_bytes()[0] - b'a') as usize;
        let child = &self.children[index];
        if child.is_none() {
            return;
        }
        child
            .as_ref()
            .unwrap()
            .add_word(s.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
    }
}
```

and the error is `cannot borrow data in a` & `reference as mutable cannot borrow as mutable`. I'm open to other fixes not directly related to my question that may yield more idiomatic Rust code. Like, I believe I could have used `unwrap_or_default` in places but my attempts led to a bunch of other scary errors that didn't get easily resolved by following clippy's advice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify anything behind a `&` reference i.e even if your `self` is mutably borrowed, you are taking an immutable reference to its inner field.

`let child = &self.children[index];`

You can replace the following code with refutable pattern matching.

```rust
 if child.is_none() {
   return;
 }
 child
  .as_ref()
  .unwrap()
  .add_word(s.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
```

with

```rust
 if let Some(ref mut child) = self.children[index] {
   child.add_word(s.get(1..).unwrap_or_default());
 }
```

The `ref mut` takes a mutable reference to the `child` after matching on `Option<Box<Trie>>` which is basically `*self.children[index]`. This will take care of the `cannot move out of a reference` error for you since it does not implement `Copy` and is a behind a reference.